# What does it mean when "In a data set, there are as many deviations as there are items in the data set."?

Tags: statistics

I'm studying introductory statistics and the textbook mentioned this text:

If x is a number, then the difference "x – mean" is called its deviation. In a data set, there are as many deviations as there are items in the data set.

Can someone aid me in understanding what it means when it says that there are as many deviations are there are items in the data set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means that every item in the data set has a deviation associated with it.

For example, if your data set was expressed as a vector $(1, 2, 3, 4)$, the associated deviations would be $(-1.5, -0.5, 0.5, 1.5)$, because the mean is 2.5. There are four of each.

Comment: Oh, I see now! Thanks so much!

Comment: @user65141 Don´t forget to mark the answer as accepted ($\color{limegreen}{\checkmark}$). Thanks.

Comment: I did! Thanks so much guys!